# How can I create small tableView controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, view, tableview, viewcontroller

I need create this table but do not know that objects do I need to use and what logic I need to create it?

[image]

Comment: Check this sample:  https://github.com/satishazad/SAMenuDropDown

Answer (score 2):

Please check this links :

http://www.raywenderlich.com/29472/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-in-ios-6-uipopovercontroller-tutorial

http://code4app.net/ios/ZSYPopoverListView/51aae6396803fa3e0f000002

might be helpful in your case.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no default way to achieve something like this. But there are a lot of example with source code. [See this link](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=dropdown).

You'll find a lot of controls of this type. You can also get the source from here. Pick any one and read the documentation carefully. Hope you;ll understand.